# How to downgrade MS SQL Server 2019 Enterprise (evaluation) to Standard (purchased)?

Tags: database, sql-server, database-administration

SQL Server 2019 was installed in evaluation edition. When entering the activation code for a purchased copy of Standard edition I received the following message:

[image: pic1]

I entered the activation code that is correct for SQL Server 2019 standard. I can’t understand why the reports show that Enterprise is installed if when install was  the evaluation version.

[image: pic2]

How can I install and activate the Standard version of the SQL server 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[Supported version & edition upgrades (SQL Server 2019)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15)
says this:

> Upgrading from Evaluation (a free edition) to any of the paid editions is supported for stand-alone installations, but is not supported for clustered installations.

So what you are trying to do is feasible.

Details on the procedure can be found in the article
[Upgrade to a Different Edition of SQL Server (Setup)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15).

In a nutshell, try first the
"SQL Server Installation Center", click Maintenance, and then select Edition Upgrade.

If this fails, try it from `setup.exe` of the Standard version.

If all fails, uninstall the Enterprise evaluation version and install the Standard
version.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not solve my problem, as I have an activation key for the Standard version. but my instance after installation for some reason becomes Enterprise, why? (or, if I use the activation key for Enterprise, then I can activate it.)

Comment: If your installation has become corrupted and does funny stuff, uninstall and reinstall should solve it.

Comment: Or, if the installation media is bad, try to download it again (maybe for [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads#)). Is it possible you got an Enterprise serial by mistake?

Comment: maybe the key is not correct, I wrote to the local supplier.

Comment: The cause of the problem was that the reseller provided the another activation key.

Answer (score 0):

Check for capitalization, G=6 and other similar mis-typings.  Maybe your code is invalid because it has been used by others?  Call Microsoft as a next step.

Comment: The activation key is 100% entered correctly.
why after installing the evaluation edition in reports it shows that enterprise is installed?

Comment: I don’t believe it’s possible to downgrade from Enterprise to Standard.

Comment: Agree.  Might have to uninstall and reinstall standard.  Not sure as I've never tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for a downgrade from Enterprise to Standard edition you have to [run the setup file](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/upgrade-sql-server-evaluation-edition-to-license-edition-of-sql-server). Please check your 1st screenshot and click on "Edition Upgrade".

Comment: Unfortunately this will not solve my problem, as I have an activation key for the Standard version. but my instance after installation for some reason becomes Enterprise, why? (or, if I use the activation key for Enterprise, then I can activate it.)